# AudioContext how to play the notes in a sequence

Tags: javascript, sequence, audiocontext

I have followed this [tutorial](http://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/) and come up with that code:

```
context = new AudioContext();
play(frequency) {
    const o = this.context.createOscillator();
    const g = this.context.createGain();
    o.connect(g);
    g.connect(this.context.destination);
    g.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(
      0.00001, this.context.currentTime + 1
    );
    o.frequency.value = frequency;
    o.start(0);
  }
```

This way I can play any notes from [tutorial](http://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/) table by passing the values `1175`, `2794`, etc

I decided to create an array of notes and just called my `play` function in the loop and it is just didn't work as all the notes just played at once with no delay.

How would you play the array of notes in a sequence?

I also was looking in to that [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer) but still cant figure out how I can adapt my code above to that.

Comment: On your other question: `while(true){for(i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){ doStuff(i); } for(i = array.length; i-- > 0; ){ doStuff(i); } }`. Just keep it simple, don't overthink it.

Answer (score 7):

You can play notes in sequence with an additional parameter *time* in your play function.This way you can control start time and end time for each note in the sequence.

```
  var context = new AudioContext();

  var notes = [1175, 2794];
  var duration = 1;
  var interval = 2;

  function play(frequency, time) {
    var o = context.createOscillator();
    var g = context.createGain();
    o.connect(g);
    g.connect(context.destination);
    g.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(
      0.00001, context.currentTime + duration + time
    );
    o.frequency.value = frequency;
    o.start(time);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    play(notes[i], i * interval);
  }
```

However, if you need a more precise/robust scheduler, you can use a library like [WAAClock.js](https://github.com/sebpiq/WAAClock) or take inspiration from Chris Wilson [metronome](https://github.com/cwilso/metronome/) to build your own.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the operations you are doing are non blocking in JavaScript. The most straightforward way to force a delay between these is to use setInterval and setTimeout. I found examples of using those in [this article on using AudioContext](https://modernweb.com/audio-synthesis-in-javascript/).

[setInterval on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) 
[setTimeout on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

The difference is that setTimeout executes once after a delay, whereas setInterval executes repeatedly until you tell it to stop.